# How far can you detect a train on a railway track?

Tags: acoustics

I'm trying to find some data, about how far you can hear a train comming, if you put your ear onto the tracks.

I tried searching but without any luck.
Also, i'm not sure how to calculator it either.

I would love your input!

Comment: Why the dislike?

Comment: Seems to me that this is more of a human physiology question than a physics one.

Comment: It's a great physics problem. Perhaps helpful is [Chapter 2](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwji4_3RgovYAhVG2WMKHZJxAv8QFggsMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fcda%2Fcontent%2Fdocument%2Fcda_downloaddocument%2F9783319493480-c2.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-1599948-p180420946&usg=AOvVaw2qpbY27yydtM8eKDvMsvvU) of "Acoustic Emission: Methodology and Application" by Zinoviy Nazarchuk.  It's entitled "Propagation of Elastic Waves in Solids".  See especially sections 2.1.8 and 2.1.9. on plates and bars.

Comment: Thank you very much for information @D.Betchkal -  i appreciate  that :)